# pandas replace items in df from mappings defined in separate df

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following two DataFrames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'name': ['Johnny', 'Sara', 'Mike']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': [2, 1, 2]})
```

How can update `df2` from the mappings defined in `df1`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Sara', 'Johnny', 'Sara']})
```

I've done the following but there has to be a better way to do it:

```
id_to_name = {i: name for i, name in zip(df1['id'].tolist(), df1['name'].tolist())}
df2['name'] = df2['name'].map(id_to_name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way :-) I learn it recently

```
df1.set_index('id').name.get(df2.name)
Out[381]: 
id
2      Sara
1    Johnny
2      Sara
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Very nice! Learned something new.

Comment: That is great! Its the same as `df1.set_index('id').name[df2.name]`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `Series`/`dict` to `map` (thanks to piR for the improvement!) -

```
df2.name.map(dict(df1.values))
```

Or, `replace`, but this is slower -

```
df2.name.replace(df1.set_index('id').name)
```

```
0      Sara
1    Johnny
2      Sara
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: You remember this one (-:  `df2.name.map(dict(df1.values))`

Comment: `dict(df1.values)` is causing a `ValueError`